# How disable horizontal scrolling in FlatList component

Tags: react-native

I have the following FlatList Component in my app but even when I set horizontal prop to false it still let me move the screen horizontally when I'm scrolling.

```
 <FlatList
    data={props.data}
    renderItem={({ item }) => props.renderItem(item)}
    horizontal={false}
    contentContainerStyle={{
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
    }}
  />
```

Comment: delete `horizontal={false}` since it's vertical by default, and please make sure that you are reloading the app

Comment: Seems like FlatView needs to be wrapped into  a <View> component

Answer (score 9):

As of my understanding, you want to show a list of items horizontally but it should not scroll the list.

If it is the case then in flatlist use:
`horizontal={true}
scrollEnabled={false}`

Comment: That worked.
But in my case, I had to add the FlatList into <View style={{flex: 1}}></View>
Without it, it might not work. In my case, I had to belong it into View with flex.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your FlatList is meant to scroll vertically but is also scrolling horizontally, and you want to prevent that horizontal scrolling.

Locking horizontal or vertical scrolling is totally possible, using FlatList's `directionalLockEnabled` prop. This prop inherits from ScrollView and you can read more about it here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview

Note: Users will still be able to scroll horizontal if they intentionally scroll horizontally. The effect of this prop is locking a user to a vertical or horizontal axis once they begin to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <FlatList
    data={plannedJobs}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
    horizontal={false}
  />
</View>
```